# caffe: How to interpret EuclideanLoss (pixel-wise regression)

Tags: python, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have and image as input and an image as ground_truth. My last layer is a `EuclideanLoss` where the last `convolutional` layer has `num_output = 1` in order to calculate the loss between these two images.

When testing the network with my `deploy.prototxt` I am omitting the `EuclideanLoss`-layer which means that my last layers are a `Convolutional` layer followed by a `Relu` layer. How do I have to interpret the values when I retrieve them via Python as:

```
pred = net.forward()

output_blob = pred['result']
```

output_blob is of shap `1xheightxwidth` but the values are not in a specific range. They can even be negative. How do you retrieve the proper values to create an image? Or how do I have to interpret these values? Do I have to substract them from the input image or how should I treat them?

Comment: How can output_blob values be negative since it is the output of a ReLU layer?

Comment: Because of that: `relu_param{ negative_slope: 0.01 }`. @Dale

Comment: What is your objective? What are you trying to implement?

Comment: I have an input image and as ground_truth I have the corresponding depth image. (Both are scaled in protoxt from [0, 255] to [0, 1] @malreddysid

Comment: --> Depth Estimation. is that answer enough? @malreddysid

Comment: Hmmm.. I would try to classify into output into 256 levels if the euclidean loss isn't working.

Comment: This is exactly what I am doing, and then it works. But why is that?? That is so weird. I do not understand that. The problem is I later wanna work with 3D images --> then it would be way easier to work with EuclideanLoss rather than SoftmaxLayer. Read about it here: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980772/caffe-confused-about-regression). I am a bit helpless there. Would be nice if you could give me some input! @malreddysid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that your output should be non negative, why use a ReLU with negative slope?, I would change it for a regular ReLU layer.
Then, after using forward(), you should get the output data like this:

```
output_data=output_blob.data[...]
```

that output could have a shape like Batch,nchannels,H,W.
You can use `output_data=np.squeeze (output_data)`
to have the output as a 2D matrix.

EDIT:
The way to interpret the last layer values would be, that it is the image that is the closest (in terms of L2 distance) to the depth estimations seen during training for the given input.

Comment: Ok, I have several ReLU layers. Is it enough to just change the last ReLU layer or do I have to change all of them? And the other question is, why is it a problem that the values are negative? I mean even when I have the 2D matrix I still do not know how to interpret the values?

Comment: It should be fine changing only the last layer. After training, when you test a new input image for which you don't provide a label (depth), the last layer is actually the depth estimation, that is, every value in the 2d matrix would represents the depth of the corresponding pixel. That's why having negative depths wouldn't make sense. Also, if all your depth estimations should be in the range [0,1], you could use a sigmoid instead of a ReLU to ensure the proper range.

Comment: Ok, yeah I change the values from [0, 255] in the beginning since these are the values from the png to [0, 1] and then later I convert them to [0, 255] again. I will try to use a `Sigmoid` layer instead and then the 2D matrix should be only multiplied by 255 and the reuslt should be the estimated depth values?

Comment: It seems like you might be able to help with a further problem related to this question. Because I was able to achieve depth estimation by classification but not regression (which should be the other way round since depth estimation is a regression task) I have asked this question: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40588551/caffe-how-to-convert-network-from-pixel-wise-segmentation-to-pixel-wise-regress). I would very appreciate it if you could have a look at it and give me your thoughts even if you might not know the answer.

Comment: Ok what your *EDIT* basically says is I can use that 2D matrix and multply by 256 --> so that I can save the image as png? Thanks for having a look at the other quesiton! I will close-accept the answer as soon as this conversation here has satifsfied me, but I gave you an upvote already!

Comment: you can multiply this matrix by 255 (the rang is 0-255) for 8 bit images. Is that the range of your depth image?

Comment: My depth images and my input image range from [0, 255] however I scale them in the data layer to [0, 1]

Comment: ok, then I would use a sigmoid layer instead of ReLU (giving the range [0-1]), and then, rescale it to the original range by multiplying by 255.

Comment: Just one sigmoid layer at the end are you sure? I mean obviously the sigmoid layer produces output from [0, 1] but if I use ReLU and then just use sigmoid once to achieve [0, 1] sounds a bit weird to me

Comment: why? the main objective is to use non-linear activation functions, and ReLUs have proved to work well in different tasks. The fact that you combine ReLUs with one sigmoid at the end would not be a problem.

Comment: What I mean is not use a ReLu and then a sigmoid, but rather remove the last ReLU and use a sigmoid...

Comment: Yeah, can you explain why? Rather than just say cause the output is from 0 to 1

Comment: I mean there is not a final choice here, using ReLU can be a good option, but of ourse your output can have values larger than 1. Then is up to you how to transform those values in the correct range. There are several options, like threshold everything above one and then multiply by 255, or use the full range and normalize...

Comment: Yeah this is exactly what I do.

Comment: ok, so what exactly is your question? if it's about the performance we can't tell with the details given, and the question about how to retrieve the output data from the blob is in the answer

Comment: Yeah I think your answer is correct! Can you have a look at this. I think this is a more precise question: [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40980772/caffe-confused-about-regression)