# caffe: Confused about regression

Tags: classification, regression, deep-learning, caffe, conv-neural-network

I have a really weird problem I want to explain to you. I am not sure if this is a topic for SO but I hope it will be in the end.

My general problem task is depth estimation, i.e. I have an image as input and its corresponding ground_truth (depth image). Then I have my net (which should be considered as black box) and my last layers.

First of all depth estimation is rather a regression task than a classification task. Therefore I decided to use a `EuclideanLoss` layer where my `num_output` of my last `Convolution` layer is 1 --> output is `1xheightxwidth`. The net converges and the loss value in the end is `3`. When I try to create my estimated output image by using my `deploy.prototxt` where I remove the `EuclideanLoss` layer. My las layer then is a `ReLU` layer like this:

```
layer {
    name: "relu"
    type: "ReLU"
    bottom: "conv"
    top: "result"
    relu_param{
    negative_slope: 0.01
        engine: CUDNN
    }
}
```

My problem is: the estimated depth image does not even look like my ground_truth. Ok well first that sounds a bit like yeah you have a net and it does not work. But when I alter my task into a classification task which should be less suited for this approach I get really good results. By altering it to a classification task I mean exchanging the `EculideanLoss` layer with a `SoftmaxLayer` and rather than `num_output = 1` in the last `Convolution` layer I have `num_output = 256` For `256` depth values where 0 is black and 1 is white.

I am really confused since the regression task should work better in theory than the classification task. Can anyone help me with this problem? Is there any big mistake in my thoughts? Or did I forget something which is really important to do for regression?

Any answers are really appreciated!

Comment: In my work we have found that just changing one layer from a classification network in order to build a regression network is not enough. In fact, the regression task is much harder than the classification one. You should try a different architecture, and also change the hyperparameters; e.g. We have found that the learning rate should be considerably smaller for the euclidean loss. Obviously this depends on how the network is behaving, if the loss is decreasing, how the validation set is doing ,etc...

Comment: Ok, I think my network itself is really strong. But I could think about it. Do you think decreasing the number of ground_truth values could help. As in rather than having values from 0 to 255 with stepsize one I would have values like 1, 4, 8, .. 255. (And then I would scale them again). Have you found about sth about scaling as well? Because when I scale my network from [0, 255] to [0, 1] my loss converges, Otherwise it doesnt. What was your loss value? I thought a loss value of 3 might have been good enough. @RogerTrullo

Comment: Do you have a link to your work? @RogerTrullo

Comment: We still have not published our results as it is an ongoing work. But I can tell you that at least in our case (3D data), we need a completely different architecture and regularization (like batchnorm..) ,etc.

Comment: Ok, are you learning sth from 3D to 3D? Are you using caffe? And how does your network roughly look like? @RogerTrullo

Comment: Can we have a chat somewhere? @RogerTrullo

Comment: Have you got some news? I am still very intereset. Maybe you could give me some interesting links, or describe your solution a bit more. I am using recurrent convolutional neuronal networks @RogerTrullo